# Elasticsearch: is bulk search possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

i know there is support for bulk index operation. but is it possible to do the same for search queries? i want to send many different unrelated queries (to do precision/recall testing) and it would probably be faster using bulk query

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and the `/_msearch` endpoint to send as many queries as you wish in one shot.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_msearch -d '
{"index" : "test1"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 10}
{"index" : "test2"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
'
```

You'll get a `responses` array with the response of each query in the same order as in the request.

Note:

1. make sure to separate each line by a newline character
2. make sure to add the extra newline after the last query.

Comment: Is the same available for count? Edit: _msearch + size: 0 does the trick